# dc js - unable to redraw charts

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

I've created few graphs using the `dc.js`. Everything runs very smooth.

But the problem is when I try to add `reset` button for some reason it's not working.

Below is the anchor tag I'm using to reset the graph.

```
<a class="reset" href="javascript:Chart1.filterAll();dc.redrawAll();" style="display: none;">reset</a>
```

Someone help me if i'm missing anything. I couldn't get any documentation of the reset stuff.

Comment: When you say that it's not working, what do you mean? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: The chart doesn't reset when i click on the reset button.

Comment: And do you get any error messages?

Comment: No error messages. Nothing happens when i click on the reset `a` tag.

Comment: Hmm, looks like it should work. Could you post a complete example?

Comment: Here's the [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Bra2H/8/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem was that you were defining your chart variable inside the local scope of the Javascript code executed at the beginning. This means that it wasn't accessible from the scope of the button Javascript, which generated an error.

To fix, simply remove the `var` from the definition of the chart variable. Complete example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Bra2H/9/).

Answer (score 0):

Could not make it work with Lars's answer.

What helped me was making the chart variable global:

```js
window.myChart = new dc.RowChart('#myId');
```

This made it available later in the JS snippet executed on click of the reset link.